# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException code was working earlier now it doesnt work

Tags: java

```
private void jLabel23MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {          

     Scanner sc; 

     try {

       sc = new Scanner (new FileReader("src\\main\\Profiles.txt"));
        String name, newPrice,fname,lname,male,female,a,cin,add,group;
        String line ="",content="";
            name = userNameField6.getText();


        while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                line = sc.nextLine();
                Scanner lineinput = new Scanner(line);
                lineinput.useDelimiter("/");
                String gr = lineinput.next();
                String firstname = lineinput.next();  
                String lastname = lineinput.next();
                String age = lineinput.next();
                String gender = lineinput.next();
                String contact = lineinput.next();
                String address = lineinput.next();


                if(name.equals(firstname))
                {



                    line = "";

                }
                content = content +line;

            }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Profile Has Been Deleted");

                sc.close();
                FileWriter writer,writer2;
                try {
                    writer = new FileWriter("src\\main\\Profiles.txt");
                    writer2 = new FileWriter("src\\main\\Profiles_1.txt");

                writer.write(content);
                writer.close();
                 writer2.write(content);
                writer2.close();


                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        }

}
```

it would show me this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHUle.png)
This code was working earlier then all of the sudden it stopped working. basically what it does is only change an line of text file to a blank one. Im new to programming and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing GUI exception - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Vector Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811795/java-swing-gui-exception-exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-util-nosu)

Comment: Looks like one of `lineinput.next()` throws this `NoSuchElementException`. It means that not all lines in our file have all fields. You could try to add `lineinput.hasNext()` check before every `lineinput.next()` or just use `line.split("/")` instead of `lineinput` `Scanner` and check the length of array.

Comment: @dmitrievanthony thanks found out that there has been an empty space at my text files.